# Dialog not called in ExtReact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, extjs

So, I want to combine Panel with Dialog, once I click on the gear button (shown on the picture), I want for a dialog to pop up. But it is like it doesn't even call the function showDialog(). Most important parts of the code are shown below, after the picture.

[image]

-Needed functions:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showDialog: false,
            idOfPortletLocation: '',
            text: '',
            portletlocation: []
        };
    }

    showDialog(){
        this.setState({ showDialog: true });
    }

    onOk(){
        this.setState({ showDialog: false });
    }

    onCancel(){
        this.setState({ showDialog: false });
    }
```

-Render part of the code:

```
<Container layout="fit"> 
                <Panel 
                    ref={panel => this.panel = panel}
                    title= {this.state.text.title} 
                    tools={[ 
                        {type: 'minimize', handler: () => this.toolHandler("minimize", this.state.idOfPortletLocation)},
                        {type: 'maximize', handler: () => this.toolHandler("maximize", this.state.idOfPortletLocation)}, 
                        {type: 'close', handler: () => this.toolHandler("close", this.state.idOfPortletLocation)},
                        {type: 'gear', handler: () => this.showDialog}
                    ]}
                    bodyPadding={10}
                    ref="target"
                >
                    {this.state.text.description} 
                </Panel>
                 <Dialog
                    displayed={showDialog}
                    title="Dialog"
                    closable
                    maximizable
                    closeAction="hide"
                    maskTapHandler={this.onCancel}
                    bodyPadding="20"
                    maxWidth="200"
                    defaultFocus="#ok"
                    onHide={() => this.setState({ showDialog: false })}
                >
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                    commodo consequat.'
                    <Button text="Cancel" handler={this.onCancel}/>
                    <Button itemId="ok" text="OK" handler={this.onOk}/>
                </Dialog>
            </Container>
```

Comment: isnt it this.state.showDialog in your dialog attributes?

Comment: No, look at the answer below from @Evan, that is the solution! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the function, you should have:

```
{type: 'gear', handler: () => this.showDialog(); }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct solution! :) Thank you very much! :) It usually worked without braces in React, but I guess this is ExtReact... :)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Ext. The portion after the fat arrow is the body of a function. `handler: this.showDialog` would be roughly equivalent (give or take the this` pointer).